# Cache and outputcache

Tags: asp.net, caching

What is the difference between property Cache and OutputCache directive?

Answer (score 4):

Cache is where you can put data - stuff coming from the database, or as the result of an expensive calculation, for example.  Anything in cache should be available to all users.

OutputCache caches HTML - an entire page, or the output from a user control.

Comment: Then I need to use OutputCache always?! And sometimes - Cache. Right?

Comment: Is Cache shares data between users?

Comment: with OutPutCache property, the page cached in server, when client request the page. IIS will serve the cached page without rendering again. For more informatin http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121306-1.aspx

Comment: Then I need to use OutputCache always?!

Comment: That depends on how often the underlying data changes, and what type of performance problems you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can make a desition in your deep heart that both of them are different.
Most of time the Cache is used as the data or business result store. So you could only process your business logic or against your DB at the first time. You'll find it's very efficient one the process need much time. You can use it in your layers: data lay, business lay and so on.

OutPutCache: It announce the IIS server, proxy, or client to cache the response result. Especially benefit for the dynamic pages. The server will response the cached result to the client once it requested before.